# what is wrong with this sql table creating (foreign key issue)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb

Error Number: 1005

Can't create table 'pyro_urbfot.default_wishlist' (errno: 150)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default_wishlist` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `url` varchar(30),
  `text` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
  `dt_added` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `position` (`position`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`uid`)
  REFERENCES `default_users`(`id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: What does the definition for `default_users` look like? And does that table definitely exist yet?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Thank you for your interest - it definately exists, I wouldn't count on that being the problem, since default_users is a core of the CMS I'm trying to integrate my wishlist module into. I did change the uid to smallint(5) just as the (id) in the default_users, but that didn't change anything

Comment: Well in that case check the datatype of `id` in that table.

Comment: @MartinSmith -  You were right, there were a discrepancy, but unfortunately I changed the uid to smallint(5) just as the (id) in the default_users, but that didn't change anything

Comment: What about signed vs unsigned?

Comment: @MartinSmith - that was very attentive of you and quite noobish of me. Thank you for your expertize you solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script works fine for me when I create this table first

```
CREATE TABLE `default_users`
(
`id` int primary key
)
```

Please check that the table exists and you are using compatible datatypes.